# MVC EditorFor and Generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, editorfor

I have a model like this

```
class MyClass
{
}

class MyModel
{
    public EditorModel<MyClass> EditorProperty { get; set; }
}

class EditorModel<T>
{
   public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

and razor view template under EditorTemplates folder like this

```
@model Project.EditorModel<MyClass>

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyProp)
```

and Index razor view

```
@model Project.MyModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EditorProperty)
```

But when I run the code to render the template, the template is not rendered, instead what is rendered is a string with the full name of the type used as a model in the editor template view.

Is the problem that EditorFor method doesn't support generic models? is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML output?

Comment: Why is `EditorModel<T>` a generic-type if it doesn't use `T` anywhere?

Comment: @JuanR It just post a simple text for the model type name with no HTML tags in the place where it supposed to display the view.

Comment: @Dai This is a simplified example, but of course in the real code the `EditorModel` uses the `T` in some of its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem starts with the template name, which cannot really satisfy the generic class name pattern. So the Template is not being picked automatically.

Method `EditorFor` also has an [override where you can pass the Template Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_5).

What you could do is to update the usage of `EditorFor`, while providing the Template Name, now the trick is to make that part dynamic, and it could also be part of your ViewModel class:

```
@model Project.MyModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EditorProperty, Model.TemplateName)
```

You need to extend `MyModel` to provide the `TemplateName` property. It's now up to you how you determine the correct name. You could make it a named pattern convention:

```
public string TemplateName
{
    get
    {
        // EditorProperty must not be null... mind this is C#6 but its easy to downgrade it
        var genericType = EditorProperty?.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
        return $"EditorModelOf{genericType}"; 
    }
}
```

And `TemplateName` will for example return

> EditorModelOfMyClass

So you should name your EditorTemplate `EditorModelOfMyClass.cshtml`. This will only work if your expected amount of generic classes is limited.